# How to dropdown selected dynamically if data in table using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have attached an image of a table. The data (language and ranking) are getting from this table via jQuery AJAX. Please check the sample image of data listing.

My issue is in dropdown I need to show retrieve data (ranking) is selected when page loads. At present German is correct means ranking shows 3 but English dropdown is showing wrong. But ranking response showing `alert(getRankingRate);` result is `2` and `3`.

```
$.get("/language/ranking/get", function(responseDB){
        var getrankingDB = '';
        var getRankingRate = 0;
        var getRankingID   = 0;
        $.each(responseDB.selectLanguageRankingTagId,function(i, item) {
          getRankingID    = item.id;
          getRankingRate  = item.ranking;
          getLanguageName = item.title_en;
          getrankingDB += '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-8"><h4 style="background-color: lightgrey; border-radius: 10px; background-repeat: repeat; height: 30px; margin:5px 0px; padding:4px 5px;">'+getLanguageName+'</h4></div><div class="col-md-3" style="padding:5px;"><select class="form-control input-sm" id="getRankingLanguage_'+getRankingID+'"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select></div></div>';
          $( ".loadlanguagemodal" ).html('<div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header loadlanguagemodal"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><h4 class="modal-title">Edit Languages</h4></div><div class="modal-body">'+getrankingDB+'<div class="appendRow"></div></div><div class="modal-footer"><div class="row"><select class="form-control input-sm"><option selected="selected">Add Language</option>'+optionLang+'</select></div><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button></div></div>').fadeIn( "slow" );
        //alert(getRankingID);
        $('#getRankingLanguage_'+getRankingID).val(getRankingRate);
        });
});
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem 1

In your html you have `class="getRankingLanguageOne_'` but then in your jQuery, you call `$(".getRankingLanguage_" + getRankingID).attr("selected", "selected");`

---

#### Problem 2

You have an issue with the logic in your loop. To explain the issue, I'll simplify your function and add some comments:

```
$.get("/language/ranking/get", function(responseDB){
        var getrankingDB = ''; // here you create a varible to hold the html for the rows
        //....
        $.each(responseDB.selectLanguageRankingTagId,function(i, item) { // here you loop over the results
          getRankingID    = item.id;
          getRankingRate  = item.ranking;
          getLanguageName = item.title_en;
          getrankingDB += '....'+getLanguageName+'...'; // here you add the html for this row to the getrankingDB variable
          $( ".loadlanguagemodal" ).html('...<div class="modal-body">'+getrankingDB+'<div class="appendRow">....').fadeIn( "slow" ); // here YOU SET THE CONTENTS OF modal-body TO THE RAW HTML VARIABLE getrankingDB ON EVERY ITERATION OF THE LOOP
          $('#getRankingLanguage_'+getRankingID).val(getRankingRate); // here you set the value of the current select box BUT, on the next iteration you YOU SET THE CONTENTS OF modal-body TO THE RAW HTML VARIABLE getrankingDB which overwites the changes you made here on the last iteration.
            // this means that only the very last itteration will actually get the value
        });
});
```

---

#### So, that's what's wrong, here's how I would do it.

[And a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/vbfue61f/49/)

```js
//fake data for this test
var responseDB = {
    selectLanguageRankingTagId: [{
        id: "1",
        user_id: "11",
        language_id: "English",
        ranking: "2",
        title_en: "English"
    }, {
        id: "2",
        user_id: "11",
        language_id: "German",
        ranking: "3",
        title_en: "German"
    }, {
        id: "3",
        user_id: "11",
        language_id: "French",
        ranking: "4",
        title_en: "French"
    }

    ]
}

var $languagemodal = $('#languagemodal'); // get the modal and the dialog div
var $dialog = $languagemodal.find('.modal-dialog');

$languagemodal.modal({show: true}); // just to show the modal for the demo

var optionLang = ''; // not sure what this is supposed to be...

// load the modal content div
$dialog.html('<div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header "><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><h4 class="modal-title">Edit Languages</h4></div><div class="modal-body"><div class="appendRow"></div></div><div class="modal-footer"><div class="row"><select class="form-control input-sm"><option selected="selected">Add Language</option>' + optionLang + '</select></div><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button></div></div>');

// get the modal body we just added
var $modalBody = $dialog.find('.modal-body');

// loop over your data, you would have this in your $.get function 
$.each(responseDB.selectLanguageRankingTagId, function (i, item) {
    // make the row
    var $newRow = $('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-8"><h4 style="background-color: lightgrey; border-radius: 10px; background-repeat: repeat; height: 30px; margin:5px 0px; padding:4px 5px;">' + item.title_en + '</h4></div><div class="col-md-3" style="padding:5px;"><select class="form-control input-sm" id="' + item.id + '" data-item="' + item + '"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select></div></div>')
    // set the select value
    $newRow.find('select').val(item.ranking);
    // add the row to the modal body
    $modalBody.append($newRow);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="languagemodal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog"></div>
</div>
```

This is why your code does not work, but milenvoutchev's approach would be much simpler.

The

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my code but problems not resolved

Comment: @samsam Can you post a jsfiddle with the generated html? If you could add a sample of `responseDB` that would also be very helpful

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/avkj0qwm/3/  Initially load a default language div. When we click on that div it will hide and load "loadlanguagemodal". Now in code datas are dynamic. I didn't change to static. If you need that I will convert things to static. Response datas are hardcoded in html side.

Comment: @samsam Ok , I see the problem, I have to take my kids to school. Ill finish a fix for you when I get back

Comment: @samsam You're welcome, That should get you fixed up and explain the issues.

Comment: THanks for great support I will add this and let you know urgently. var optionLang = ''; is used for getting all languages from database (Purpose is, if user need to add more language user can select language from dropdown and save)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now user language and ranking works perfectly. But below (Add language) dropdown list of languages is not working. My previous code it is working. Could you please help me to integrate that section too?

Comment: this is the code var optionLang = ''; // not sure what this is supposed to be...
 $.get("/tag/language", function(response){
     $.each(response.selectLanguageRankingTagId, function (i, item) {
  engLangID  = item.id;
                engLang    = item.title_en;
                optionLang += '<option value="'+engLangID+'" class="addMore" data-language="'+engLang+'">'+engLang+'</option>';
     });
 });

Comment: response is {"availableLanguage":[{"id":1,"title_de":"Afghanisch","title_en":"Afghan"},{"id":38,"title_de":"Afrikaans"
,"title_en":"Afrikaans"}]}

Comment: Youll have to remove this line `var optionLang = ''; // not sure what this is supposed to be...` I only put it there so that the variable would not be `undefined` and cause an error. Whatever you were doing for that before should still work.

Answer (score 1):

You can greatly simplify things here and use jQuery's behavior to select `<select>` element's option by it's 'value' attribute. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/avkj0qwm/

Your `<select>` elements should have unique IDs based on their RankingID, e.g.:

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" id="getRankingLanguage_'+getRankingID+'">
```

Then you can target the correct `<select>` and `<option>` elements, like:

```
$('#getRankingLanguage_'+getRankingID).val(getRankingRate);
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you need more info!

Comment: That would be simpler, could be even shorter with `$('#'+getRankingID).val(getRankingRate);`

Comment: I have updated my script as per your instructions but issue is not solved. Updated code is added in my question